# Are there bonuses related to mousing over multiple items dropped from buildings?

Tags: simcity-social

In Facebook games similar to Simcity Social (such as Cityville), one could obtain a bonus by consecutively mousing over icons given in the game world by interacting with buildings. Players were rewarded by chaining together a streak of collecting these items without a significant pause in between pickups.

Is there anything similar to this mechanic in Simcity Social?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You get the same results collecting them with the mouse and waiting for them to be collected automatically.